# I am using jquery form validation grouping issue

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, jquery-validate

I am using jquery form validation plugin and I am having three dropdown for birth date (date, month,year) if user have not selected any one of dropdown or all  I want to show single error message instead of three and also want to highlight the fied as well. same thing want to apply for text fied as well. Please help me I am stucked....

Comment: Put them all in the same validation group.

Comment: I answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084852/can-i-combine-the-validation-error-of-two-combo-box-using-jquery/17091228

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the link of this plugin you're using?
jQuery have many plugins to do that. If you paste a code shard your be easier to find a good answer.

Cya.

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ 
I am using this one