# Can I combine the validation-error of two Combo box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation, combobox

I am trying to validate 3 combobox which are for date, month, year.

I am using jquery.js and jquery.validate.js. It is showing errors for each combobox if it is not selected, but I want only one  message instead of 3 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are needed - add all 3 to a `group`, and setup the [errorPlacement](http://validation.bassistance.de/validate/) option to appropriately place the error message.

So if your form looks like this:

```
<form>
  <select name="day" class="required">
     <option value="">Day</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <!-- etc -->
  </select>
  <select name="month" class="required">
     <option value="">Month</option>
     <option value="1">Jan</option>
     <!-- etc -->
  </select>
  <select name="year" id="year" class="required">
     <option value="">Year</option>
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
     <!-- etc -->
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then you need a jQuery Validate call like this:

```
$('form').validate({
   groups: {
      myDate: 'day month year'
   },
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {  
     if (element.attr("name") == "day" 
             || element.attr("name") == "month" 
             || element.attr("name") == "year" )
        error.insertAfter("#year");
     else
        error.insertAfter(element);
   }
});
```

And if you put that all together you get an example that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Yzdag/

Comment: thanxx alot.
One more thing if u can help...
how do i validate the date entered above such as 30th, 31st and for leap year also , any reference 
And Thanx once again.....

Comment: Use [Datejs](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact) or the [jQuery UI Datepicker's formatDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: can you please give an example or jsfiddle like above

Comment: Probably better to ask a new question - it's a different issue entirely, and I don't actually know the answer very well!

Comment: Thanks for the help